# Pass by reference and global variables

Tags: c++, function, reference, global

I am learning about functions, references and global variables.
I have the following code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int x;
    void f(){ x = 2;}
    
    void g(int &x){ f(); }

    int main() {
        int x=5;
        g(x);
        cout<<x;
    }
```

Why don't I get 2 as output? Since x changes inside g() I would expect that value to be retained.

Comment: `cout<<x;` is printing out the local `x` defined in `main()`. Change to `cout<<::x;` to print out the global `x`.

Comment: Because `f()` changes the global `x`, not the one local to `main()`, and `main()` prints the one local to `main()`.    The fact that `main()` passes its local `x` to `g()` by reference, or the fact that the argument of `g()` is also named `x`, doesn't change that.    `g()` does not change the value passed to it as an argument, because it  (and `f()`) never use that argument.    To print the global `x` from `main()`, either rename the local `x` to something else, or print `::x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `void f()` acts on the *global* `x`. The parameter passed to `void g(int&)` is not used.

That global `x` is *shadowed* by the *automatic* `x` defined in `main()`.

Write

```
std::cout << "local " << x << " global " << ::x;
```

to see what happens to the two variables.

Comment: if i have written x=2; inside g() function, I would get that result in main(), my question is about the difference between executing f() inside g() or by assigning x=2; inside g()

Comment: If you had written `x = 2` in `g()`, then the local value of `x` in `main()` would be changed. That's because you pass that `x` by reference into `g()`.

Answer (score 0):

We can access a global variable if we have a local variable with same name in C++ using scope resolution operator `(::)`

In your main function you just need to use `cout<<::x;`

For better understanding, please see the following simple code or refer this link

> [How to access a global variable within a local scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458720/how-to-access-a-global-variable-within-a-local-scope)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int x = 5;     // Global x 
int main()
{
    int x = 2; // Local x
    cout << "Value of global x is " << ::x << endl;
    cout << "Value of local x is " << x;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```